# SQLAlchemy Session.commit() hangs

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, tornado

I am using `scoped_sessions` from SQLAlchemy (to MySQL) and running the SQL commit inside tornado's threadpool. In my unit test, the first time `Session.commit()` passes but the second `Session.commit()` hangs. I am closing the session properly after the first time commit. I enabled SQLAlchemy logging and I can see that there is nothing emitted after `INSERT INTO ...` for the second commit.

Comment: More info: the objects that I am trying to commit are the declarative base models objects and they get assigned an id as auto-increment id from the mysql. The commit above is actually inserting that object into database.

Answer (score 2):

Having same issue (hang in later commit) brought me to this question earlier today. I've managed to resolve the issue by making sure that only one session is in place.

In my case I'm running integration tests with session test for each test and doing roll back in tear-down as [described in docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites). I've got all DB stuff wrapped in DatabaseService class which is responsible for the test setup (a derived TestDatabaseClass doing the session setup in ctor).

The problem was that I managed to initialize the DatabaseService instance (with test setup) twice and experienced the hang in the later created nested session's commit (or in explicit flush call). So making sure that only one DatabaseService exists and all DB queries goes thru one session did resolve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

What does you session init look like? Are you not using `autoflush`? Try calling `session.flush()` after the commit.

Comment: my init looks like : scoped_session(sessionmaker()). I tried adding the flush() after commit.. still gets stuck at the second commit. These are just two test that I am running so I doubt I am using up all the connections from the pool.

Comment: Is part of the tested code creating the original Session?  Is there an rc file that lets you skip the `bind=engine` arg?


Example from the docs:

```>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

>>> session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
>>> Session = scoped_session(session_factory)```

Comment: Thanks Chris. The problem was that I had a pending transaction in between the two tests. That was causing the next commit to just not  happen.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I had a pending transaction in between the two tests. That was causing the next commit to just not  happen.

Comment: How did you diagnose that you had a pending transaction? And how did you fix it?

Comment: Same question from me.